# How to test if item exists in recordset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a crosstab query that is being loaded into a recordset. I'm then writing the query fields to an Excel spreadsheet. The problem is that a field may not exist based on the query results.

For example, I have the following line:

```
oSheet5.Range("F1").Value = rsB2("AK")
```

...which would write the value of the recordset item named "AK" to the spreadsheet. But if "AK" doesn't exist, I get an error `Item not found in this collection`.

How I can I test to see if there's an item named "AK"?

I tried...

```
If rsB2("AK") Then
    oSheet5.Range("F" & Count).Value = rsB2("AK")
End If
```

...but that didn't work.

I also tried...

```
If rsB2("AK") Is Nothing Then
    oSheet5.Range("F" & Count).Value = ""
Else
    oSheet5.Range("F" & Count).Value = rsB2("AK")
End If
```

...and still the same error.

There are 50+ items/fields to check .. all states in USA plus a few extras.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an error handler to catch the item not found error ... ignore it and/or do something else instead.

Or if the first recordset field always maps to the first sheet column regardless of the field's name, you can reference it by its ordinal position: `rsB2(0)`

Or you could examine the recordset's `Fields` collection to confirm the field name is present before attempting to retrieve its value.

After you open the recordset, load a dictionary with its field names.  This code sample uses late binding.  I included comment hints in case you want early binding.  Early binding requires you to set a reference for *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*.

```vb
Dim objDict As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary
'Set objDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim fld As DAO.Field

For Each fld In rsB2.Fields
    objDict.Add fld.Name, vbNullString
Next
```

Then later you can use the dictionary's `Exists` method to your advantage.

```vb
If objdict.Exists("AK") = True Then
    oSheet5.Range("F1").Value = rsB2("AK")
End If
```

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do .. examine the recordset to see if a field named "AK" exists before accessing it's value. How is that done? Something like `If rsB2("AK") exists then cell.value = rsB2("AK")` .. I just don't know the VBA syntax :)

Comment: The Excel file looks like `F1 = "AK", G1 = "AL", H1 = "AR"` .. So F2 would have to be `rsB2("AK")`, G2 would have to be `rsB2("AL")` .. etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Recordset.FindFirst Method (DAO)` take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194787.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165283%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Small example:

```vb
Sub FindOrgName()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

'Get the database and Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblCustomers")

'Search for the first matching record   
rst.FindFirst "[OrgName] LIKE '*parts*'"

'Check the result
If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Record not found."
    GotTo Cleanup
Else
    Do While Not rst.NoMatch
        MsgBox "Customer name: " & rst!CustName
        rst.FindNext "[OrgName] LIKE '*parts*'"
    Loop

    'Search for the next matching record
    rst.FindNext "[OrgName] LIKE '*parts*'"
End If

Cleanup:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Although this works, Recordset.Findfirst can be painfully slow. I think it ignores indexes. You might be better off with Recordset.Seek.